# Book about a kid who gets recruited into a think tank via computer game

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for this book that I read a long time ago (early 2000s). This kid loves playing this certain computer game and is exceptionally good at it. In the game, there was a riddle that went something like "*How much dirt is in a hole that has a radius of 33.2 meters and a height of 78.2 meters?*" The kid's answer, which was correct: "*None. A hole doesn't have anything in it*". This particular book had a blue cover.

He beats the game and gets recruited by a guy and joins a think tank. The guy who recruits these kids is actually evil. Every morning, these kids take a "vitamin pill" which actually controls them. This girl tells the protagonist to not take the pill. He slowly realizes that the guy is actually evil.

There was a scene where the protagonist is told to eat the eggs first as it gets cold easier. In the end, all the kids were saved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Brainboy and the Deathmaster](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2645918-brainboy-and-the-deathmaster)* by Tor Seidler

> Darryl Kirby is an orphan. He is also a whiz at computer games -- especially those conceived by Keith Masterly, the greatest software guru of all time. But when Darryl plays a new prototype of his favorite game, StarMaster, strange things begin to happen. After he finds his way through a tortuous maze and answers questions that could stump a scientist, a mysterious message -- "WANT TO PLAY?" -- invites him into a game in which the stakes are higher than they first appear -- a game that eventually lands him in a luxurious laboratory where Masterly has enlisted a brain trust of children for a secret purpose of his own. Befriended by Nina, who suspects Masterly's motives, Darryl slowly uncovers a sinister plan and finds himself the star in his own real-life computer game. But will he and Nina be able to stop Masterly and escape before it is too late?

[The Kirkus Review of the book](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/tor-seidler/brainboy-and-the-deathmaster/) mentions the daily pills.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you add some details that explain how this matches the question?  You might want to read [answer].

Comment: THIS IS THE BOOK! THANK YOU!

Comment: You’re welcome! It was a really good book, just sad it never got a sequel!

Comment: Hi can you [edit] in more details of why this is correct? The OP has accepted it, but it would be good for future visitors of the site.

Answer (score 4):

This could potentially be the second book in Gillian Cross's Demon Headmaster series, [The Prime Minister's Brain](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1660558.The_Prime_Minister_s_Brain). A new computer game, Octopus Dare, is the latest craze at school, but only Dinah is good enough to beat it. After beating it she receives a letter inviting her to London to take part in a national competition, the Junior Computer Brain of the Year. Once there, it turns out the Demon Headmaster was behind the computer game, which hypnotises its players. He was using it to select intelligent children he could bring together (the Brains) and hypnotise into helping him crack the security that would give him access to the Prime Minister, so that he could then hypnotise him and take over the country. Dinah's friends in SPLAT follow her to London, and together they manage to thwart the headmaster's plans again and free the Brains.

Comment: That is not the book unfortunately. It's not a series. It was just that one book. Thank you though!